# Flash data, or session messages in Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

In advance I apologize if this is a repeat/legacy question, I just couldn't find any related resources for this issue.

I am looking to show temporary user alerts when the user sends a delete, post update request (Think rails/laravel session flash messages) to let them know if it was successful or not. In previous projects I would user a small JQuery script to display the message for a couple seconds and have it disappear on its own.

Are there some related animation fade in/out functions that I can use for this?

Currently I am using QuerySelector to add the message to an alert div, but I am unable to make the alert disappear automatically.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification would be a possibility

Comment: Do you want "flash data/session storage" or do you want a UI element to be shown to the user? They are sort of unrelated. I think Gunter has covered probably one of the best options for the UI (native to the browser platform).

Comment: I suppose I was looking for the UI solution, my wording I admit may have been misleading. Thank you for your suggestions.